# How to retrieve data from all pages?

Tags: android, backendless

I want to get some data from all users in `Users` table. I've found that I have to use `Data paging`. I've written the same code as described in Feature 47->https://backendless.com/feature-47-loading-data-objects-from-server-with-sorting/ (because I also 
have to sort) , but then I've figured out that this code takes data only from first page. Then , I decided that I have to go to the next page and read it , until its size is not equal to zero. Below,you can see my wrong solution:

```
 QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() ;
    list.add("point DESC") ; 
    queryOptions.setSortBy(list);
    BackendlessDataQuery backendlessDataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    backendlessDataQuery.setQueryOptions(queryOptions);

    Backendless.Data.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(backendlessDataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> one) {


            while(one.getCurrentPage().size()>0) {
                Iterator<BackendlessUser> it = one.getCurrentPage().iterator();

                while (it.hasNext()) {

                //something here,not so important 



                }

                one.nextPage(this);// here I want to get next page,
              //but seems like it does not work, cause my loop became infinite







            }







   }
```

I think that I have to use nextPage method with AsyncCallback instead of `one.nextPage(this)` , but if I do so , the method couldn't keep up with the loop. So, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Try using events; so basically, when first call completes, pass the next_page_token to the calling class; then initiate the next http request with that token; that also means you won't be doing loops

Comment: for backendless version 5.x.: https://backendless.com/docs/android/doc.html#data_file_paging

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't find the problem with your solution, but I solved this problem using:

int tot = response.getTotalObjects()

to get the total number of objects at the first response. Then use a loop until your list of objects has size = tot. In each loop you make a query setting the offset equals to the current size of the list.

Comment: I've understood that `getTotalObjects()` method returns all amount of records in table.But why I need it? Now,I have 17 users in my table , and I want to go through all of them. First page's size is 10 , it means I get 10 users. 7 users left. Then I want to get next page that has rest 7 users. How can I take next page? According to your answer , I've writtent code , but it seems that it is wrong , cause there is a infinite loop. Please help.
`while(response.getCurrentPage().size>0){`

Comment: `while (one.getCurrentPage().size()>0) {
offset+=one.getCurrentPage().size() ;
Iterator<BackendlessUser> it = one.getCurrentPage().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
//something
}
one.getPage(10,offset,this);//seems like this line is incorrect,why?
}

`

Comment: You can set the offset in the QueryOptions and than increasing each time the offset until it gets equal to the total objects. Unfortunately I can't help you with that code because I don't know how the paging system really works

Comment: One thing you can improve is getting 100 elements at each call instead of 10

Comment: Yes,I can get 100 elements , but anyway, if I have 200 users , I have to know paging unfortunately